# Docker-Cloud CLI Error on Windows

Tags: python, windows, pip, docker-cloud

I'm trying to install the Docker-Cloud CLI with pip, and it installs successfully.  However, when I check the version (as suggested by the site), I get the error in the paste below.  I'm running Windows 10 and Python 3.6.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aglas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\docker-cloud-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('docker-cloud==1.0.7', 'console_scripts', 'docker-cloud')()
  File "c:\users\aglas\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 565, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "c:\users\aglas\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2631, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "c:\users\aglas\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2291, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "c:\users\aglas\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2297, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "c:\users\aglas\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\dockercloudcli\cli.py", line 10, in <module>
    from dockercloudcli import commands
  File "c:\users\aglas\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\dockercloudcli\commands.py", line 15, in <module>
    from dockercloudcli import utils
  File "c:\users\aglas\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\dockercloudcli\utils.py", line 16, in <module>
    from exceptions import BadParameter, StreamOutputError
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exceptions'
```

Comment: Double check that your package is supported in Python 3. It seems to be trying to import the `exceptions` module, but I tried this on my local Python 2 and it works, but not on my local Python 3.

Comment: Please see [issue 21](https://github.com/docker/dockercloud-cli/issues/21) on GitHub. It seems it does not support Python 3.